# Rails Byebug gem: How to create a conditional breakpoint on a variable assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

How do I create a conditional breakpoint in Byebug about a variable assignment? This is more an event than a condition. But how would you proceed if you do not know where in the code the assignment could happen?

Watching a variable in *step by step* manner isn't delivering results. I would need to watch it, until some arbitrary value is assigned to the identifier.

I only know that an Identifier is somewhere in the Rails program, maybe even in the initialization process, is assigned a value to. I don't know when or what. The "what" is what I want to find out. Is there a debugging solution?

Answer (score 2):

E.g. if you know that the variable starts off as nil

```
byebug unless x.nil?
```

Then scatter that statement around your code wherever that variable is in scope and you suspect it may be changed. Or if you want to restrict it to a certain operation or loop, set a global variable where you want to start looking like

```
$enable_byebug = true if name == 'foo'
do(something)
...
byebug if !x.nil? && $enable_byebug
```

This is one of the few contexts where I'm happy to use global variables.